# How to Turn contents of .txt file into a list and print random item from that list

Tags: python, list

No errors, but when I try to print a random item it will only print the last item of the .txt file every time.

How can I turn my text file into a list? More specifically how to turn the entire left side of a .split into a list?

Any insight you may have is welcomed!

**My .txt file is formatted like so.**

Ano Iyan? = What's That

Marunong ka bang mag-Ingles? = Do you know how to speak English?

May telepono ba dito? = is There a telephone here?

```
import hashlib
import random

testFile = ""
def qSearch():
    options = input ("Vocab/Grammar/or Special? (v/g/s)")
    if options == "v":
        testFile = "Vocabtest"
        Vocab()
    elif options == "g":
        Grammar()
        testFile = "Grammartest"
    elif options == "s":
        Special()
        testFile = "Specialtest"
    else:
        qSearch()

def Vocab():
        with open('Vocabtest.txt','r') as f:
            for line in f:
                questions, answers = line.split("=")
            print (random.choice([questions]))




qSearch()
```

(return in terminal)

Vocab/Grammar/or Special? (v/g/s)v

May telepono ba dito?

Comment: What is the point of the variable `testFile`?  You never use it.

Comment: I had planned to take that out actually. It was originally there to be used 
 for something like // with open( testFile + '.txt', 'r' ) as f: // I see now that it was unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Vocab()` function is reading all the data, but NOT saving that data in any significant or useful way. In the revised code below, we store all the question/answer pairs into a dictionary.

Having the data in a dictionary allows us to query the dictionary for a key to get the paired value.

Just prior to randomly choosing a key (using `random.choice`, we will convert the dict.keys() object to an indexable list.

```
def Vocab():
    with open('Vocabtest.txt','r') as f:
        q_and_a = dict()                           # creates a dictionary
        for line in f:
            question, answer = line.split("=")
            q_and_a[question] = answer             # stores the question and answer

    keys = list(q_and_a.keys())                    # create a list of keys
    print(q_and_a[random.choice(keys)])            # randomly selects a key 
                                                   # (question) and uses it to get
                                                   # an answer.
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It clears up the logic for me, however I maybe should have mentioned I am writing Python 3 and this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I am getting ///TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing/// Something is not a list?

Comment: Same error has occurred. Thanks for helping out btw! If possible, can you explain what's going wrong exactly or what the error entails?

Comment: @Thrifts I replaced the `print()` line with: `print(q_and_a[random.choice(keys)])` 
... give that try.

Comment: Looks like it works! It returns random string from answer. I can work with this.

Comment: One more quick question @E.Ducateme! Sorry I'm still getting my head around working with lists. Is there anyway I can call the answer of that random question after?

Comment: Nevermind! Read up on dict () and figured it out. Thank you for you help though!

Comment: @Thrifts if the  answer provided solves your question, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I think I accepted it by pressing the check. If not please tell me how!